# Debugging a Java Maven Project In Netbeans Doesn't Work

Tags: java, maven, debugging, netbeans

I have a java maven project that I am running on Netbeans 11 on a Mac with jdk 14. The program is a simple java project running locally and doesn't have any connections to databases or anything. When I set breakpoints to debug a method and run Debug Project, the project runs normally and it ignores all breakpoints. How can I make it stop at breakpoints?

Comment: Does the debugger start?  Is the JVM started with the debug command line flags?

Comment: Debugger starts and the variables page says no variables to output and the breakpoint page shows where I have breakpoints set. The debug button is configured with the following arguments                                                                       
`exec.args=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address} -classpath %classpath ${packageClassName}`                                                                `exec.executable=java`                                                                                                          `jpda.listen=true`

Comment: Is this accessible on github or another public repository?